# Creating rollback in rest calling soap

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap

I have a restful webservice that is supposed to be a travel agency that is a client of two soap webservices a flight service and a hotel service. the soup webservices have three methods. Getflights/hotel, book flight/hotel, cancel.
the book in flight charges cash from the creditcard.

In the restfulService there is a bookall method that shouls book all flights and hotels. If one of them fails it should not book at all!
I am not sure how to implement that. It is a study project. Any help would be appreciated. If something is unclear just ask.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually implement this functionality similar to the database rollback. i.e if any one failed then apply cancel on all reserved in this cycle.